# React Native picks single json_encode string but not the array

Tags: php, react-native, fetch

I am trying to return array from PHP to React Native via Fetch. As long as the returned variable is a single one it works fine but when I return an array the response becomes empty.

My PHP Code

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

    }else{
        parse_str($_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'], $get_array);
        $_GET = (array) $get_array;
        $_POST = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    }


    $to_return = array();
    if(isset($_GET['token']) && $_GET['token'] != ''){

        if(check_token($_GET['token'])){

            if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '' && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] != ''){



                $user = wp_authenticate( $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] );
                if($user){
                    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
                    delete_user_meta( $user->ID, 'api_token');
                    add_user_meta( $user->ID, 'api_token', $token);
                    $to_return['token'] = $token;
                    $to_return['result'] = 'user logged in successfully';

                }else{
                    $to_return['result'] = 'user not authorized';
                }
            }else{
                $to_return['result'] = 'parameters are missing2';
            }
        }else{
            $to_return['result'] = 'invalid token';
        }
    }else{
        $to_return['result'] = 'parameters are missing1';
    }
        //this line works fine
        echo json_encode($to_return['token']);
        //this line gives emoty response
    echo json_encode($to_return);
```

My React Native Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, AsyncStorage, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import FormData from 'FormData';

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

  login = () => {


    url = 'https://foodtest.cloudaccess.host/wp-json/v1/login_customer?token=********';
    var object = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: '**********@network-source.com',
        password: '*******',
      })
    };

    fetch(url, object)
    .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => { console.log(responseData); })
      .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Login Screen</Text>

        <View style={styles.field_cont}>
          <Text>Email</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, width: '100%' }}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.field_cont}>
          <Text>Password</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          />
        </View>

        <Button
          title="Login"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Login"
          onPress={this.login}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  field_cont: {
    padding: 10,
    width: '100%'
  }
});
```

I am using Reactotron for viewing the return value. It shows empty for second line in PHP and single variable is successfully shown.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify something, the error is when you try to handle the response on React Native or when you try to send the response on PHP?

Comment: The error occurs when I change the value in PHP from single variable to array.If I echo json_encode single_variable it is ok the variable is return and shown in console. But when I change it to echo json_encode Array then the response becomes empty. I want to return an array from PHP to React Native thats all I want to do.

Comment: Then your problem is with PHP and not with React Native, or am I wrong?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with it. It returns the array but React Native is unable to read it. Read the above things then you will get it.

Comment: does response.text() return anything?

Comment: Yes response.text is returning the string for json. I will try this and update here !!!

Comment: I'll add the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because the parsing of the JSON is being strange, try `response.text()` and see how the JSON string returns.

Also add a PHP Header for `content type application/json` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The above answer was also a miss in the PHP code and also you need to return the json_encode. The problem was that I was echoing it. Thanks for the help !!!